# Where clause for equals a field, not equal another

Tags: mysql, sql

It's been one of those days and I just can't figure this out.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 80
```

Obviously, this selects all of the posts that are in the category ID 80. What I need to do is select all the posts that are in category 80 but NOT in category 109.

I've tried this, but it just selects the same posts from category 80.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 80
AND term_taxonomy_id = 109
```

Here's the table structure:

```
wp_posts

|    ID    |
------------
|    1     |
|    2     |

wp_term_relationships

| object_id | term_taxonomy_id |
|-----------|------------------|
|     1     |       80         |
|     2     |       80         |
|     1     |       109        |
```

object_id matches to post_id

The query should only return ID 2 since ID 1 is in both 80 and 109.

I know I've done this a million times but I just can't for the life of me get this to work. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
  JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 80
   AND wp_posts.id NOT IN
        ( SELECT object_id
            FROM wp_term_relationships
           WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 109
        )
;
```

(See [§ 13.2.10.3 "Subqueries with `ANY`, `IN`, or `SOME`" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM wp_posts p
  JOIN wp_term_relationships t
    ON t.object_id = p.ID AND t.term_taxonomy_id = 80
  LEFT
  JOIN wp_term_relationships n
    ON n.object_id = p.ID AND n.term_taxonomy_id = 109
 WHERE n.object_id IS NULL
```

This uses a LEFT OUTER join against the term relationships table (aliased as `n`), to find matching rows in category `109`, but then excludes any rows where a match was found (via the condition in the `WHERE` clause, so ther rows returned from wp_posts that are those that are not in category 109.

In SQL parlance, we refer to this operation as an "anti-JOIN".

NOTE: This query does have the potential to return "duplicate" rows if `(object_id,term_taxonomy_id)` is not unique, for example, you have two (or more) rows in wp_term_relationships with (object_id=2,term_taxonomy_id=80).

---

In general, in MySQL, we find that JOIN operations (including anti-join operations) often outperform subqueries.

Another alternative (which is likely NOT to perform as well as the previous query):

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM wp_posts p
 WHERE EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM wp_term_relationships t
          WHERE t.object_id = p.ID 
            AND t.term_taxonomy_id = 80
        )
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM wp_term_relationships n
          WHERE n.object_id = p.ID 
            AND n.term_taxonomy_id = 109
        )
```

NOTE: It's possible that MySQL generates the same execution plan for this query (including the join and anti-join operations) as the previous one. You'd need to run EXPLAIN on the query to see the execution plan, and test whether one is "faster" than the other.

There are other approaches as well. Performance is going to depend on available (suitable) indexes, data distribution, and the generated execution plan.

Comment: +1, but re: "In general, in MySQL, we find that JOIN operations (including anti-join operations) often outperform subqueries": This is true for some types of subqueries, but from what I understand, recent versions of MySQL have no problem recognizing `IN (...)` and `NOT IN (...)` as semijoins and antijoins (respectively) and optimizing accordingly.

Comment: @ruakh... which is exactly why I recommended that `EXPLAIN` output and testing would be appropriate. It absolutely does depend on which version of MySQL. In MySQL 5.1 for example, a `NOT IN (subquery)` does not generate the same plan as from an equivalent `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NOT NULL` query. (Interestingly, the `LEFT JOIN` query shows `'; Not exists'` in the explain output, while a `NOT EXISTS` query shows a plan equivalent to a `NOT IN` query, which both show `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` in the explain output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as an aggregation query.  I like this approach because I think it is the most flexible for defining elements in a group:

```
select id
from wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_term_relationships t
     ON t.object_id = p.ID
group by id
having sum(case when term_taxonomy_id = 80 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and    -- in 80
       sum(case when term_taxonomy_id = 109 then 1 else 0 end) = 0       -- not in 109
```