# Evaluate a column so that it equals something but not something else?

Tags: mysql

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Participation(
ParticipationId INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
SwimmerId       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
EventId         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Committed       BOOLEAN,
CommitTime      DATETIME,
Participated    BOOLEAN,
Result          VARCHAR(100),
Comment         VARCHAR(100),
CommentCoachId  INT UNSIGNED,
CONSTRAINT participation_pk PRIMARY KEY(ParticipationId),
CONSTRAINT participation_ck_1 UNIQUE(SwimmerId, EventId),
CONSTRAINT participation_swimmer_fk FOREIGN KEY(SwimmerId) 
    REFERENCES Swimmer(SwimmerId),
CONSTRAINT participation_event_fk FOREIGN KEY(EventId) 
    REFERENCES Event(EventId),
CONSTRAINT participation_coach_fk FOREIGN KEY(CommentCoachId) 
    REFERENCES Coach(CoachId)
);

CREATE TABLE Swimmer(
SwimmerId       INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
LName           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
FName           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Phone           VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
EMail           VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
JoinTime        DATE NOT NULL,
CurrentLevelId  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Main_CT_Id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Main_CT_Since   DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT swimmer_pk PRIMARY KEY(SwimmerId),
CONSTRAINT swimmer_level_fk FOREIGN KEY(CurrentLevelId) 
    REFERENCES Level(LevelId),
CONSTRAINT swimmer_caretaker_fk FOREIGN KEY(Main_CT_Id) 
    REFERENCES Caretaker(CT_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Event(
EventId      INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Title        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
StartTime    TIME NOT NULL,
EndTime      TIME NOT NULL,
MeetId       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
LevelId      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT event_pk PRIMARY KEY(EventId),
CONSTRAINT event_meet_fk FOREIGN KEY(MeetId) 
    REFERENCES Meet(MeetId),
CONSTRAINT event_level_fk FOREIGN KEY(LevelId) 
    REFERENCES Level(LevelId)
);
```

There are 3 tables, I'm suppose to list the names of the swimmers who have -- participated in in event 3 but not event 4.

First I tried this: `SELECT s.FName AS "fname", s.LName AS "lname" FROM Swimmer s, Participation p, Event e WHERE s.SwimmerId = p.SwimmerId AND e.EventId = p.EventId AND p.EventId = 3 AND p.EventId != 4;`

I've been searching on online for a while now but haven't been able to find anything like this exactly.

This is the closest I got to finding a solution: [Where clause for equals a field, not equal another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396112/where-clause-for-equals-a-field-not-equal-another) but I'm not quiet sure what my "wp_posts.id" and "wp_term_relationships" would be in my situation.

Comment: There's a Boolean participated column. Why?

Comment: Oh, and tip: NEVER use comma style JOINs

Comment: posts.id is probably event id. wptr is probably participation

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new my mysql, why should I use comma style joins and where exactly am I using them? When I select s.FName and s.Lname, am I using a joing there? Or is it only possible to apply "joins" when I'm selecting specifying which tables to use (the tables I list when I use FROM)?

Comment: All of this is covered in any introductory book or tutorial . It's really basic stuff, and far too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, mate:

```
SELECT s.FName AS 'fname', s.LName AS 'lname'
FROM swimmer s
    INNER JOIN participation p ON p.SwimmerId = s.SwimmerId
    -- swimmer(s) that did not participate in event 4
    INNER JOIN participation p4  ON p4.SwimmerID = s.SwimmerId
        AND p4.EventId != 4
WHERE p.EventId = 3;
```

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting the same thing I got for the query I had, it's only returning the Swimmers who have participated in event 3 instead of returning the swimmers who participated in event 3 but did not participate in event 4.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: I am sorry to say that does not work, but since you're the only one that answered I'm going to give you the best answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got as a solution:

```
SELECT s.FName AS "fname", s.LName AS "lname" FROM Swimmer s
WHERE s.SwimmerId IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT p.SwimmerId FROM Participation p WHERE p.EventId = 3
) AND s.SwimmerId NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT p.SwimmerId FROM Participation p WHERE p.EventId = 4
);
```